# How do you write a htaccess redirect for pages which look like they're directories?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to figure out how to do a 301 redirect for a page who's URL is in the format

```
www.site.co.uk/foo/bar/
```

to a URL formatted as

```
www.site.co.uk/bar.html
```

I've tried using Redirect which didn't work and I've tried RewriteRule as well but I've not been having much luck.

Could anyone offer some help or link me to some great htaccess tutorials?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution by reading:

http://perishablepress.com/redirect-subdirectory-to-root-via-htaccess/

The htaccess code is as follows:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/bar/$ http://www.site.co.uk/bar.html
```